# How do i change for background colors or themes for all my screens while clicking one button in setting page for my app in ios, Using objectve c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibackgroundcolor

I have tried in my `viewDidLoad:` in my tableview controller, But its changing for only that screen, I need to change for all my screens.

```
self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
myTableView.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you have multiple view and you want to effect the color change in you all of the views?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/Draveness/DKNightVersion

Comment: Ha Yes, Rashad, I need to to change background color for all my view's

Answer (score 4):

**1.**

- Create a **Singleton Class** named `Settings`
- Have a property for color
- Create a `BaseViewController` and let all your **ViewControllers** inherit from this BaseViewController.
- Set the background color on `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` of your `BaseViewController`.

Ex:

```
//Settings.h
@interface Settings : NSObject

+ (Settings *)sharedSettings;

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *themeColor

@end

//Settings.m
+(Settings *)sharedSettings {

    static Settings *sharedSettings = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedSettings = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedSettings;
}

//BaseViewController.m
#import "Settings.h"

...

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[Settings sharedSettings].themeColor];
}
```

**2.**

There is another method by which you can achieve this i.e. **Notification Design Pattern**

Whenever you change the color in settings, dispatch a notification and receive that notification in your `BaseViewController`.

```
//Settings.m
- (void)colorChanged:(UIColor *)color {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ThemeColorChanged" object:color];
}

//BaseViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(@"notificationThemeColorChanged:") name:@"ThemeColorChanged" object:nil];
}

- (void)notificationThemeColorChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIColor *changedColor = notification.object;
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:changedColor];
}
```

**For Saving**

If you need to Save the Data so that whenever the user comes back to the application, he sees the last updated color, then you could save it to **UserDefaults**.

```
//Settings.h
@interface Settings : NSObject

+ (Settings *)sharedSettings;

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *themeColor

@end

//Settings.m
+(Settings *)sharedSettings {

    static Settings *sharedSettings = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedSettings = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedSettings;
}

- (instancetype)init {

    if(self = [super init]) {

        UIColor *savedColor = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ThemeColor"];
        if(savedColor) {
            self.themeColor = savedColor;
        } else {
            self.themeColor = defaultColor; //Ex:[UIColor whiteColor];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)colorChanged:(UIColor *)color {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:color forKey:@"ThemeColor"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Thanks For your response, But i need in swift language

Comment: U have asked question for objective-c code, for that this is the answer. If you want you can ask another question for swift code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:150/255 green:255/255 blue:100/255 alpha:0.3f]];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response , but i need in swift language for changing back ground image for both landscape and portrait modes

Answer (score 0):

Without saving the background color in the user defaults. the background color will reset every time app. get closed. methods to use user defaults:

```
@implementation Common

+ (id) valueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
    id val = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    return val;
}

+ (id) valueForKey:(NSString *)key defaultValue:(id)default_value
{
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
    id val = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    if (val)
        return val;
    [Common setValue:default_value forKey:key];
    return default_value;
}

+ (void) setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

@end
```

In your master view controller. a controller which all controllers subclass:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)Animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:Animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [Common valueForKey:@"BackgroundColor" defaultValue:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

In your settings page to save the color:

```
[Common setValue:[UIColor purpleColor] forKey:@"BackgroundColor"];
// or
[Common setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:125.0/255.0 blue:95.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forKey:@"BackgroundColor"];
```

> Note that you need to set your subviews background color to clearColor
>   if needed.

You can merge this solution @Burhanuddin Sunelwala solution to get a perfect one.

Comment: Thanks for ur response , but i need in swift language for changing back ground image for both landscape and portrait modes